# Why G++12 vector insert optimization breaks code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20, gcc12

Last time I've compiled my project by new GCC12 and it gave me warning about bad memmove buffer size. The previous versions of the GCC had not report such warnings.

The simple code example which presents my situation:

```
#include <vector>                                                              
#include <cstdint>                                                             
#include <iostream>                                                            
                                                                               
struct [[gnu::packed]] S {                                                     
  uint32_t a;                                                                  
  uint8_t  b;                                                                  
  uint16_t c;                                                                  
};                                                                             
                                                                               
std::vector<uint8_t> s_to_bytes(const S &s) {                                  
  S x = s;                                                                     
                                                                               
  std::vector<uint8_t> res;                                                    
  res.insert                                                                   
    ( res.begin()                                                              
    , reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&x)                                           
    , reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&x) + sizeof(S)                               
    );                                                                         
  return res;                                                                  
}                                                                              
                                                                               
int main () {                                                                  
                                                                               
  S s{1,2,3};                                                                  
  auto bytes = s_to_bytes(s);                                                  
  for (auto &x : bytes) std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << " ";               
  std::cout << std::endl;                                                      
                                                                               
  return 0;                                                                    
}
```

And when I compile this code by G++12 by command

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -Wpedantic -std=c++20 invalid_optimization.cpp
```

it prints warning:

```
inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> s_to_bytes(const S&)’ at invalid_optimization.cpp:16:5:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:431:30: warning: ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’ writing 1 or more bytes into a region of size 0 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
  431 |             __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _Tp* std::allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/allocator.h:183:40,
    inlined from ‘static constexpr _Tp* std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Up> >::allocate(allocator_type&, size_type) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/alloc_traits.h:464:28,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:378:33,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:375:7,
    inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/vector.tcc:787:40,
    inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = unsigned char*; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:1779:19,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = unsigned char*; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:1481:22,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> s_to_bytes(const S&)’ at invalid_optimization.cpp:16:5:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset 7 into destination object of size 7 allocated by ‘operator new’
  137 |         return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
```

This warning shows that `insert` into the vector was optimized to `__builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);` call, but with invalid size. The std::vector `insert` documentation tells that inserting is performed in range `[first, last)`, so the the end of the structure pointer must point to the next byte after structure, just like iterator `.end()` works, but GCC optimization makes from this valid code invalid memmove call, which probably got structure size + 1 instead of just structure size. Looks like `__builtin_memmove` got just difference of `first` and `last` pointers instead of `last - first - 1`.

My question is: is my `vector::insert` usage invalid or is it GCC12 optimization bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. But don't use `[[gnu::packed]]`, it will lead to horrible code. Copy the 3 members of S individually.

Comment: Even if `[[gnu::packed]]` is removed, compiler repots the warning. Please fill a bug report and add the link to it here please!

Comment: Looks like such bug report already exists: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100366

Comment: I did not agree, because your code did not result in a warning in gcc 11.x. As the bug you reference on is valid for gcc 11.x you should open a new one. Even if it will fixed with the referenced one, there is a good chance that is not the same reasoning. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is my `vector::insert` usage invalid or is it GCC12
> optimization bug?

This is a warning bug in gcc as mentioned in the comments. [Reduced](https://godbolt.org/z/xr67a3nds)

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<int> s_to_bytes() {
  std::vector<int> res;
  std::array<int, 4> s{};
  res.insert(res.begin(), s.begin(), s.end());
  return res;
}
```

The above code is undoubtedly well-formed, but gcc-12 gives an unexpected overflow warning for `__builtin_memmove`.

Bug filed [106199](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106199).

Comment: Thanks for you bug report to GCC, I found existing one with same problem: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100366

Comment: In the 100366 problem occures only after `clear` called on the vector, but looks like same optimization issue with different methods of optimization forcing

Comment: According @Klaus comment under my question, can you unmark your bug report as duplicate because different compiler versions are affected?

Comment: No, it's not an optimization bug, it's just a warning bug.

Comment: There is no problem with `-O1`, so at least it has something to do with the *optimization* flag, right? By the way, the libstdc++ tag of that bug was not added by me.